# Updating content between tabs binded by Preference

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a tabbed app and I have a button on one tab, when the user clicks then it increments a Preference and I want to update its value on another tab that is Binded to a label. I tried to experiment with MVVM but I couldnt figure it out.

Page 1 view:

```
  public partial class Page1View: ContentPage
     {
         public Page1View()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }
    
         private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Preferences.Set("Total", Preferences.Get("Total", 0)+1);
         }
     }
```

Page 2 Viewmodule:

```
 public class Page2ViewModule : INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
         public int Total
         {
             get => Preferences.Get(nameof(Total), 0);
             set
             {
                 if (Preferences.Get(nameof(Total),0) == value)
                     return;
                 Preferences.Set(nameof(Total), value);
                 OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Total));
             }
         }
         public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
         protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
         {
             var changed = PropertyChanged;
             if (changed != null)
             {
                 PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
             }
         }
     }
```

Here's what I done with MessagingCenter. On the button click event I sent a message like this:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

     Preferences.Set("Total", Preferences.Get("Total", 0)+1);

     MessagingCenter.Send<Page>(this, "test");

}
```

In the Page2 view module I added a constructor that subscribes to message:

```
public Page2ViewModule()

{

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page>(this, "test", (p) =>

    {

         Total = Preferences.Get(nameof(Total), 0);

    });

}
```

And that still doesn't work. But I'm not sure would this be the best way to do it? Or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: this won't work because a Preference doesn't have any mechanism to notify that it has been changed.  I'd suggest using a common VM between the two pages, or if that is not possible you can use MessagingCenter to notify each page when the Preference has been updated.

Comment: Check my updated post, i added some more code

Comment: has Page2 already been created and the Subscribe method execute **before** you call Send?

Comment: yes since they are all created as part of the tab control. However it works if I try it with Total++ but not the other way. It's updated before I switched to page 2.

Answer (score 0):

For **Jason's question: Page2 already been created and the Subscribe method execute before you call Send**, I test at my side,  Page2 is been created and the Subscribe method execute after you call Send, so I think it works fine using MessagingCenter to notify each page when the Preference has been updated.

Tab one Page.

```
 private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
        Preferences.Set("Total", Preferences.Get("Total", 0) + 1);
        label1.Text = Preferences.Get("Total", 0).ToString();
        MessagingCenter.Send<Page>(this, "test");
    }
```

Tab two page.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Total}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

 public partial class Tab2 : ContentPage
{
    public Tab2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new Page2ViewModule();
    }
}
public class Page2ViewModule : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _Total;
    public int Total
    {
        get { return _Total; }
        set
        {
            _Total = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Total");
        }
    }
    public Page2ViewModule()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page>(this, "test", (p) =>
        {
            Total = Preferences.Get("Total", 0);
        });
    }
  
  
}
```